# Копирование из одного приватного репозитория в другой

Tags: git

есть личный приватный github репозиторий. Там проект, который писал для организации.

На github Зарегистрировал новый приватный репозиторий для организации.
Как клонировать все коммиты, ветки со своего репозитория на репозиторий организации?

Мне нужно скопировать весь проект на новый репозиторий.

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой, известный мне способ - это подменить/добавить origin.

Клонируете себе репозиторий. Потом добавляете новый origin

```
git remote add new_origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git.
```

и отправляете в новый репозиторий.

```
git push new_origin
```

и готово. У этого способа есть один большой плюс - можно жить на два репозитория. Иногда это бывает супер-супер удобно, особенно при переезде с одного репозитория в другой, который не происходит в один миг. Главное, что нужно помнить, что теперь ветки могут жить в двух репозиториях и они не всегда будут полностью синхронизированы.

Что бы специфицировать, в какую ветку в какой репозиторий отправить, просто пишите 'имя origin:имя ветки'.

Но есть ещё один способ. Оказывается, в гите есть прям команда для Вашего случая.

```
git push --mirror git@github.myorg/myrepo.git
```

И она все сама сделает. Чуточку подробнее - https://gitenterprise.me/2016/03/30/how-to-migrate-a-git-repository/

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.